# How do I pass a value to an input field with a sequential ID using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick

I have an AJAX script that processes one of a number of forms on a page.  Because there are a number of forms on each page which are generated by a PHP loop, the IDs of the various input fields have a sequential number added to them, using the variable $form

Each form has two submit buttons, with a different value, which I would like to pass as a variable, using a hidden input field, to trigger different actions on processing the form, i.e.

```
<input type='hidden' id='button$form' value='' />
<button type='submit' class='submit_s' value='view' style='margin-right:20px' onclick='return setHiddenButtonValue(this.value);'>View</button>
<button type='submit' class='submit_s' value='email' style='margin-right:20px' onclick='return setHiddenButtonValue(this.value);'>Email</button>
```

The data from the form is processed using an AJAX script in the form:

```
var form_data = {
            name: $jform.find("[id^=name]").val(),
            date: $jform.find("[id^=date_hidden]").val(),
            time: $jform.find("[id^=time]").val(),
}
```

So I can add an entry for the hidden button input to this, i.e.:

```
    button: $jform.find("[id^=button]").val(),
```

And then use it in such a way:

```
    if (form_data.button == 'email') {
        $jform.fadeOut(800);
    }
```

What I can't work out how to do is how to pass the variable to the hidden button input. As you can see I have added an onclick event to each of the submit buttons, and then I was hoping that adding the following to my jQuery would work:

```
    function setHiddenButtonValue(buttonValue)
{
    $j("[id^=button]").value = buttonValue;
    return true;
}
```

But it's not working.  Could someone set me straight?

Comment: Uhm, why don't you use `.val()` as in `form_data.button.val(buttonValue)` or `$j("[id^=button]").val(buttonValue);`?

Comment: @Alexander I'm not sure where you are suggesting I include this.  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can modify hidden inputs in all browsers. also, I am afraid there is no .value() method within jquery :) So just use `$j("[id^=button]").val(buttonValue);` or `.attr('value', buttonValue);`

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried both versions and the button value is not getting set.  When I add it manually it gets passed to my scripts OK.  I am using Safari, so it may be related to the browser.  Is there an alternative method of passing a different value depending on whether the 'View' or the 'Email' button is clicked?  This is all I am trying to do.

Comment: I think I solved this by scrapping the hidden input, adding the class 'email' and 'view' to the respective submit buttons, and then adding a check to the submit click function to see if the class 'email' or 'view' exists, i.e. `if($jthis.hasClass('email'))`.  From here I can set a variable and pass this to the form_data